# undefined values fetched from URL params in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-services, angular-http

I am trying to fetch URL params using ActivatedRoute in Angular 2. It was actually fetching values earlier but when restarted the server it is fetching as undefined.

**This is my component code:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        var theAccessToken = params['accessToken'];
        var theRefreshToken = params['refreshToken'];
        var theLivePortalID = params['livePortalId']; 
        var theDemoPortalID = params['demoPortalId']; 

        localStorage.setItem('theAccessToken', theAccessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('theRefreshToken', theRefreshToken);
        localStorage.setItem('theLivePortalID', theLivePortalID);
        localStorage.setItem('theDemoPortalID', theDemoPortalID);

        console.log(theAccessToken);
        console.log(theRefreshToken);
        console.log(theLivePortalID);
        console.log(theDemoPortalID);
      });

   this.surveyService.getSurveysToken().then(surveys => {
       console.log("After Hit" , surveys);


       var theAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("theAccessToken");
       var theRefreshToken = localStorage.getItem("theRefreshToken");

       console.log(theAccessToken);
       console.log(theRefreshToken);

       this.surveys = surveys;
       this.surveyToken = Object.keys(this.surveys);

       console.log("Token message: " ,surveys["message"]);
       console.log("Token value: " ,surveys["data"].token);
       console.log("Token message: " ,surveys["status"]);


       if (surveys["message"] == 'Token generated') { 
          localStorage.setItem('theListingToken', surveys["data"].token);
          this.surveyService.getSurveysList().then(surveys => this.surveys = surveys);
      } else {
        alert("Error: List not found")
      }
    });
```

**This is service:**

```
getSurveysToken(): Promise<Survey[]> {
    console.log("Before Hit Token ",this.adminToken);

    var theAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("theAccessToken");
   var theRefreshToken = localStorage.getItem("theRefreshToken");



    var data = {
      access_token: theAccessToken,
      refresh_token: theRefreshToken,
    }

    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(this.adminToken, data)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json() as Survey[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getSurveysList(): Promise<Survey[]> {

   var theLivePortalID = localStorage.getItem("theLivePortalID");
   var theDemoPortalID = localStorage.getItem("theDemoPortalID");
   var theListingToken = localStorage.getItem("theListingToken");


   console.log("Before Hit surveyList ",theListingToken);

    var data = {
      live_portal_id: theLivePortalID,
      demo_portal_id: theDemoPortalID,
      token: theListingToken
    }

    console.log(data);

    return this.http.post(this.surveysListing, data)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json() as Survey[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Which part of the code is returning undefined?

Comment: all the fetched params are showing undefined. console.log(theAccessToken);
        console.log(theRefreshToken);
        console.log(theLivePortalID);
        console.log(theDemoPortalID);

Comment: try using params instead of queryParams and see if it creates any difference